# How to Get a html page content using Inet in vb6 and put the content in a TextBox?

Tags: vb6, web-scraping

How to Get a html page content using Inet in vb6 and put the content in a TextBox ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sample code in [Retrieving Data Using Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384072%28VS.85%29.aspx) article.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Function GetHTMLCode(Optional strURL As String) As String
    Dim objHttp As Object, strText As String
    Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHttp.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHttp.Send ("")
    strText = objHttp.responseText
    Set objHttp = Nothing
    GetHTMLCode = strText
End Function
```

OK?)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use vb6 webbrowser control.Using this you can get html page and of course according to html tag,input id etc.